# How to write a type instance for a compound type having existentially quantified type variables?

Tags: haskell, typeclass, existential-type, associated-types

I have a typeclass with an associated type:

```
class Foo a where
  type Bar a :: *
  ...
```

Now, I'd like to instance this class for a compound type containing existentially quantified type variables:

```
data Blat = forall a. Blat a

instance Foo Blat where
  type Bar Blat = ???
```

In my actual application, the "???" needs to make use of the existentially hidden "a" in `Blat a`, in order for the program logic to be correct.

Is this doable in Haskell?
If so, how?

===

In response to @leftaroundabout 's request for full disclosure of my original intent:

I'm trying to build representations of types, using only a small set of "primitives" (i.e. - unit, sum, and product).
And, for compound types, I'd like to enlist the help of the pre-existing representation instances for the fields making up the new type.
For explicitly parameterized field types this is straightforward.
However, I'd like to be able to do it for field types using existentially hidden type parameters, also.

Answer (score 3):

It can't be done. An existentially quantified type is only chosen at runtime, whereas a type family instantiation (associated or otherwise) must be fixed at compile time.

This is probably an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Instead of an associated type family, you should deal with the type information in some other way, but it would require knowledge of the problem you're trying to solve to say how.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've edited the original post with my original intent, as you've requested.

Comment: Ok, but this description is a bit vague. Perhaps you should properly explain it in a new question. What you want might be only doable with Template Haskell, or simply with GHC generics.